# Why is show dbs saying I haven't saved anything in mongo console?

Tags: mongodb, insert, console

I am just getting started with mongodb and I'm currently just messing around with the console. I have run both.

```
> db.something.insert({"cmon": "plz"})
> db.teams.save({country:"England",GroupName:"D"})
```

They both get a response of `WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })`.

I can also access the inserted data when running `.find()`, however I keep getting this when I run `>show dbs`

```
admin  0.000GB
local  0.000GB
mydb   0.000GB
```

Does this mean none of my data is actually persisting? Why would this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is normal, because you probably don't have much data in the collection. Try this to grab more information on the specific collection.

```
 use mydb
 db.stats()
```

You should get something like this (Here is some arbitrary data):

```
{
"db" : "mydb",
"collections" : 1,
"objects" : 10,
"avgObjSize" : 237.6,
"dataSize" : 2376,
"storageSize" : 36864,
"numExtents" : 0,
"indexes" : 1,
"indexSize" : 36864,
"ok" : 1
}
```